# Matrix Completion SDP Relaxation and Duality

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, matrix-completion

I am studying the matrix Completion problem, as well as its SDP relaxation. However, I am having trouble deriving the final SDP form of the matrix completion problem. I will give some background, which mainly comes from (ZHA) below.

### Nuclear Norm Minimization

The matrix completion rank minimization form can be relaxed as a nuclear norm minimization problem, as the nuclear norm is the convex envelope of the rank of a matrix (ZHA).

$$
  \label{eq:nuc_min_raw}
  \underset{X \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}}{\text{minimize}} \quad ||X||_* \\
  \text{subject to} \quad X_{i,j} = M_{i,j} \; \forall i, j \in \Omega
$$

We can rewrite the nuclear norm using its dual norm, the operator norm

$$
  \label{eq:op_norm}
  \underset{X \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}}{\text{min}} \quad \underset{Y \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}}{\text{max}} \langle X , Y \rangle \\
  \text{subject to} \quad ||Y||_{\text{op}} \leq 1 \\
\text{and} \quad X_{i,j} = M_{i,j} \; \forall i, j \in \Omega
$$

The operator norm constraint can be written as the Linear matrix inequality $\begin{pmatrix} I_m & Y \\ Y' & I_n \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$. To understand this, consider the following equivalencies, and then using a schur complement like argument.

$$||Y||_{\text{op}} \leq 1 \iff \\
\frac{||Yx||}{||x||} \leq 1 \quad \forall x \iff \\ 
\langle Yx, Yx \rangle \; \leq \; 
\langle x, x \rangle \; \forall x \iff \\
\langle(YY^* - I)x, x \rangle \; \leq 0 \iff \\
(I - YY^*) \succeq 0 
$$

Now we need to consider the dual of the resulting SDP:

$$
  \label{eq:matcomp_sdp}
  \underset{X, Y \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}}{\text{max}} \quad \text{tr}( X Y ) \\
  \text{subject to} \quad \begin{pmatrix} I_m & Y \\ Y' & I_n \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
\text{and} \quad X_{i,j} = M_{i,j} \; \forall i, j \in \Omega
$$

Zhao claims the dual of this SDP is

$$
  \label{eq:matcomp_dual}
  \underset{W_1, W_2 \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}}{\text{min}} \quad \frac{1}{2} (\text{tr}( W_1 ) + \text{tr}( W_2 )) \\
  \text{subject to} \quad \begin{pmatrix} W_1 & X \\ X' & W_2 \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
\text{and} \quad X_{i,j} = M_{i,j} \; \forall i, j \in \Omega
$$

How is this dual problem derived? What am I missing? It would be greatly appreciate if you could either reference a derivation, or explain the dual variables that are introduced, etc.

[ZHA]: *Zhao, Yun-Bin*, [**An approximation theory of matrix rank minimization and its application to quadratic equations**]
(http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2012.02.021), Linear Algebra Appl. 437, No. 1, 77-93 (2012). [ZBL1242.65086](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.65086).

Comment: What is $\mathbf{tr}(X,Y)$?

Comment: sorry that should just be $\textbf{tr}(XY)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation of this dual is provided in example 8.8 "Sum of singular values revisited" of [section 8.6 "Semidefinite duality and LMIs" of Mosek Modeling Cookbook 3.2.1](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/duality.html#semidefinite-duality-and-lmis).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, however I am still having trouble deriving the relationship. Would you mind explaining how they "go back from the dual" and what variables are introduced?

Comment: Read from the beginning of section 8.6 so that you understand how to take the dual of a semidefinite program (LMI problem). It is then a straightforward matter.